# Integration of CVS in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, cvs, xcode7

I am using XCode 7.0 and need to integrate a CVS repository.I have searched SO and haven't found any useful hints.The resources on internet also are fragmented and of not much help.They are using older versions of Xcode and hence many features used in the videos are not in the latest version of xcode.If anyone has done CVS integration with Xcode and willing to share the link describing the same,that would be helpful.I am already doing it using smartCVS client but no success till now.
Thanks

Comment: Modern Xcode versions don't support CVS, as not many people use CVS anymore.  You should migrate the code to using git.

Comment: @Droppy thanks for the info but the repository being used is CVS only and that won't be changed.All the back end as well as Java code is in CVS so it won't be possible to move to git.

Comment: That just means you cannot use source control within Xcode (no big deal).